# Lost a new file change in git

Tags: git, caching, commit, visual-studio-2022, restore

I was working on a project in VS 2022. I made some changes and commited them (without pushing), wanted to test something, ran my app, it crashed and my VS blew up and got closed. After I opened VS again, I didn't see my commit... Part of the change was adding a new file.
I tried running  `git fsck --lost-found` and I found changes I did to the files that existed in the branch before. However, I can not find the newly added file. The only place I found mentions of the new file is `ActivityLog.xml`. This is what I found in my ActivityLog.xml (the new file that I lost is called NewFile.cs):

```
untitled:Untitled-1 {"typeId":""}
  <entry>
    <record>919</record>
    <time>2023/02/10 20:44:11.695</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>window manager</source>
    <description>Restoring pin state failed for hash -228547614. 
     c:\git\test\myserver\NewFile.cs||{A6C744A8-0E4A-4FC6-886A-064283054674},
     
      
  </entry>
```

Is there any way for me to restore the file using information from this Log? Thanks everyone in advance...

I also found some file called "OmniSharp Log.log" and I see the following message there:

```
   NewFile.cs was added to the workspace
```

Comment: If you actually committed the change, then it should be straight forward to find it with `git reflog` on your machine.

Comment: @TTT I feel like when it blew up it really messed something up and it didn't get committed. I tried git reflog and I could find the changes I made in the commit I am talking about - all of them, except adding the new file. I feel like the new file might have get marked as "miscellaneous" and not get committed or something...

Comment: Does VS have a per file history ? (not related to git, some feature that would keep the history of files each time you hit `Ctrl+S`)